# How to execute a callable in a given context (locals and globals)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a `callback` callable that was calculated inside `exec()`.

I have `_globals` and `_locals` that were used in this `exec()`. There is a value with a key `variable_from_context` in `_locals`.

But when I try to call the `callback()`, it's executed in the current context, and not in its original context. It cannot find `variable_from_context`.

`exec()` only takes a `str` or a code object. I found this way to access the `callback`'s code object, and trying to invoke this:

```
exec(callback.__code__, scenario._globals, scenario._locals)
```

But again, I get `NameError: name 'variable_from_context' is not defined`.

What is the right way to call `callback` with the given `globals` and `locals`?

Code example:

```
der_callback = None

def save_callback(cb):
    der_callback = cb

_locals = {}
_globals = {'save_callback': save_callback}

text = r'''
zoo = ['we']

def foo():
    print(zoo[0])

save_callback(foo)
'''

exec(text, _globals, _locals)
print(_locals)

# One can also try this:
# exec(_locals['foo'].__code__, _globals, _locals)

# EDIT: Now, why doesn't _locals get used when invoking a function?
# This works:
# exec('print(zoo[0])', _globals, _locals)

# EDIT continues: This doesn't:
# exec('foo()', _globals, _locals)

_locals['foo']()
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
{'zoo': ['we'], 'foo': <function foo at 0x1020b2d90>}
  File "/Users/me/pyzoo/callback_from_eval.py", line 22, in <module>
    exec(_locals['foo'].__code__, _globals, _locals)
  File "<string>", line 5, in foo
NameError: name 'zoo' is not defined
```

Comment: Can you please post a [mcve] that reproduces this problem?

Comment: Added, also fixed a mistake: changed `eval()` to `exec()`.

Comment: Are you familiar with decorators? I believe it would be a better resource to use here, both from a usability standpoint and from a maintenance standpoint.

Comment: @Mikael To a certain degree. To use instead of what, it's a bit unclear?

Comment: Maybe it's just personal preference, but I don't like to use `exec`, because it kinda block the flow of the code in my mind. Decorators feel more familiar and are more portable and robust, I think

Comment: Sorry, decorators are not applicable here - it's an embedded Python scripting that does need `exec()`.

Comment: Are you _certain_ that you _really_ need to use `exec`? `eval` and `exec` should generally be avoided because they can be a security risk unless you have complete control over the code that's being executed. For details, please see [Eval really is dangerous](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html) by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.

Comment: @PM2Ring Can you imagine embedding Python as a scripting language without exec()? 'Don't do that' is sometimes not an answer at all.

Comment: I didn't say "Don't do that". I merely asked if you're sure that you actually need `exec`. Certainly,  there _are_ cases when you need `exec`, otherwise Python wouldn't have it. ;) But I feel obliged to post the standard warning whenever I answer an `exec` / `eval` question.

Comment: @VictorSergienko just to be  general, Python allows direct building of AST trees and executing them; it's more cumbersome than providing code to be parsing, but suggests a path without exec().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, any context has its globals and locals. On a module level, they are equivalent (the same dictionary). In other contexts, they generally differ. Unless you declare something as `global`, any assignment modifies the context locals, but not globals.

Then, any function has its own locals. As result, when entering `foo`, `_globals` is seen as globals, but `_locals` is not seen as locals. So, `zoo` is not visible. The direct fix is to say `global zoo` before its assignment in the chunk.

Also, you expose the same issue in `save_callback`: assignment to `der_callback` does not change globals, but a local variable that is immediately lost after exit. To fix, declare `der_callback` as global inside the function.

UPD: if you need chunk-top locals, you can try one of the following tricks:

T1. On chunk global level, assign a name to locals() and reuse it in foo():

```
globals()['xl'] = locals()
zoo = ['we']

def foo():
    print(xl['zoo'][0])
```

T2. Use call stack frames lookup:

Outside of chunk:

```
def save_callback(cb):
    global der_callback
    der_callback = lambda: cb(sys._getframe(1).f_locals)
```

In foo definition:

```
def foo(xl):
    print(xl['zoo'][0])
```

Comment: Indeed, thanks, making all globals helps, though it's not pretty. Do you have any insights on why doesn't `exec(_locals['foo'].__code__, _globals, _locals)` work? Plus, can I avoid globals? Locals are supposed to inherit the enclosing locals, can I do it for a callable?

Comment: Locals really do not inherit the enclosing locals or enclosed ones. In a function body, locals are the same space on all nesting levels.

Comment: Wait, in the example, if I change `save_callback(foo)` to just `foo()`, `foo()` will have access to `zoo`. `zoo` is in `_locals`. Apparently, `foo()` gets it from enclosing locals. Why doesn't passing `_locals` to `exec()` have the same effect? (I suspect `__code__` implementation specifics, but it could also be my lack of understanding).

Comment: @VictorSergienko no, with such update, `foo body` gets `zoo` from globals. You can verify it with direct check like `globals().get('zoo')` and `locals().get('zoo')`.

Comment: I'm asking about the original code. What is the point of passing `locals` to `exec()`, if it's not used? I believe it's designed to work :) But why not in this case?

Comment: Of course, locals _are_ used. The separation goal, IMO, is 1) to keep consistency with the generic principle (not only in exec()), 2) to limit unintentional changes to variables only to locals, which can be revised later on.

Comment: Then why doesn't `exec('bar()', _globals, _locals)` work? I've added two commented out lines in the end of the code exmple.

Comment: `foo` is sucessfully called. The issue it can't find `zoo` is the same as I described: unless `zoo` is global or explicitly found from the upper frame, it is present in upper locals, not in globals. With my suggestions from the first part of the answer, it prints `zoo`.

Comment: I think now I get it. `_locals` are used in a local context in `exec()`, but not in an enclosing context for a function invocation. The latter is supposed to be captured when the function is declared. Why isn't it there is a subject for another question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As Netch has said, your

```
def save_callback(cb):
    der_callback = cb
```

does *not* assign to the global `der_callback`. It binds the `cb` object to the *local* name `der_callback`, and of course that binding is lost when the function exits. To assign to a global object from inside a function you must use the `global` directive.

Perhaps this code will help you to understand what's going on.

```
der_callback = None

def save_callback(cb):
    global der_callback 
    der_callback = cb

def show_dict(d, name):
    print(name)
    for k in sorted(d.keys()):
        if not k[0] == '_':
            print('{!r}: {!r}'.format(k, d[k]))
    print()

text = r'''
zoo = ['we']

def foo():
    print(zoo[0])

save_callback(foo)

show_dict(globals(), 'text GLOBALS')
'''

_globals = {
    'save_callback': save_callback,
    'show_dict': show_dict,
}
exec(text, _globals)

zoo = ['hello']

show_dict(globals(), 'module GLOBALS')

print(der_callback)
der_callback()
```

**output**

```
text GLOBALS
'foo': <function foo at 0xb71d5cd4>
'save_callback': <function save_callback at 0xb725553c>
'show_dict': <function show_dict at 0xb71d5c8c>
'zoo': ['we']

module GLOBALS
'der_callback': <function foo at 0xb71d5cd4>
'save_callback': <function save_callback at 0xb725553c>
'show_dict': <function show_dict at 0xb71d5c8c>
'text': "\nzoo = ['we']\n\ndef foo():\n    print(zoo[0])\n\nsave_callback(foo)\n\nshow_dict(globals(), 'text GLOBALS')\n"
'zoo': ['hello']

<function foo at 0xb71d5cd4>
we
```

In both contexts `locals()` is the same as `globals()`, which you can see by passing `locals()` to `show_dict`.

---

Here's a slightly modified version of your code, I think it does what you want.

```
der_callback = None

def save_callback(cb):
    der_callback = cb

_globals = {'save_callback': save_callback}

text = r'''
zoo = ['we']

def foo():
    print(zoo[0])

save_callback(foo)
'''

exec(text, _globals)
_globals['foo']()
```

**output**

```
we
```

That `exec` call is equivalent to

```
exec(text, _globals, None)
```

Comment: I don't see how can you not reproduce the error on 3.6.0. I get it for both `foo()` invocation variants on 3.6.0 (v3.6.0:41df79263a11, Dec 22 2016, 17:23:13)  and 2.7.10 (default, Feb  6 2017, 23:53:20) on OS X. What output do you get on an unmodified MCVE?

Comment: So one half of the answer is that `globals` is already set. Do you see how to set `locals` as a, for example, enclosing locals? One may think that `exec()` will do that, and why it doesn't?

Comment: @victor I'm not sure what you're asking. Do you mean like `exec(text, _globals, locals())`?

Comment: I mean that context consists of globals and locals. The answer has dealt with globals. I have got `_locals` out of `exec()`. Now it would be nice to pass them as an enclosing locals to the next `eval()` or another way of invoking the `callback`.

Comment: @VictorSergienko Sorry for the delay. I was on my phone last time I replied, and didn't get a chance to run any code. I also apologize for saying that I couldn't reproduce your error, I don't know what I did differently last time, maybe it was because I added a `global` directive to `save_callback`. Anyway, I've added some more code to my answer.